# AIML - Wild Card Tags

Tags: aiml

I am writing the below AIML code.

```
<aiml>
<category>
<pattern>test</pattern>
<template>This is a test to try the third possible input. Yes / No ? </br> 
</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>Yes</pattern>
<that>This is a test to try the third possible *</that>
<template>Hey!. You have typed YES!</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>No</pattern>
<that>This is a test to try the third possible *</that>
<template>Hey!. You have typed No!</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>*</pattern>
<that>This is a test to try the third possible *</that>
<template>BINGO!!!!</template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

I would like to see "Bingo!!!" as a response when a user enters anything apart from Yes or No.

```
<pattern>*</pattern>
```

works fine when I use it separately, but not here. Where am I doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some AIML libraries require the `pattern` value to be uppercase (this is good practice even for implementations which not force it). So for me the following code works as expected (tested under PyAIML):

```
<aiml>
    <category>
        <pattern>TEST</pattern>
        <template>This is a test to try the third possible input. Yes / No ? <br /></template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>YES</pattern>
        <that>THIS IS A TEST TO TRY THE THIRD POSSIBLE *</that>
        <template>Hey!. You have typed YES!</template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>NO</pattern>
        <that>THIS IS A TEST TO TRY THE THIRD POSSIBLE *</that>
        <template>Hey!. You have typed No!</template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>*</pattern>
        <that>THIS IS A TEST TO TRY THE THIRD POSSIBLE *</that>
        <template>BINGO!!!!</template>
    </category>
</aiml>
```

Output:

```
> test
This is a test to try the third possible input. Yes / No ?
> yes
Hey!. You have typed YES!
> test
This is a test to try the third possible input. Yes / No ?
> no
Hey!. You have typed No!
> test 
This is a test to try the third possible input. Yes / No ?
> Foo
BINGO!!!!
>
```

Instead of `<that>` tags you can also try to use `<topic>`, e.g.:

```
<aiml>
    <category>
        <pattern>TEST</pattern>
        <template>
            This is a test to try the third possible input. Yes / No ? <br />
             <think><set name="topic">THREE OPTIONS</set></think>
        </template>
    </category>

<topic name="THREE OPTIONS">
    <category>
        <pattern>YES</pattern>
        <template>Hey!. You have typed YES!</template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>NO</pattern>
        <template>Hey!. You have typed No!</template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>*</pattern>
        <template>BINGO!!!!</template>
    </category>
</topic>
</aiml>
```